# How to get auto generate id in ES by using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to store the unique auto id like using XPOST

because every time I start the program, the data is overwritten.

but, I can't find an example that automatically generate id in Python

Could you tell me if there are any good examples?

my code:

```
def saveES(output,es):
    bodys=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(output)-1:  #output[len(output)-1] is space
            json_doc=json.dumps(output[i]) 
            body = {
                    "_index":"crawler",
                    "_type":"typed",
                    "_id":saveES.counter,
                    "_source":json_doc
                    }
            i+=1
            bodys.append(body)
            saveES.counter+=1
    helpers.bulk(es,bodys)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this in python -- if you index documents without an id, Elasticsearch will [automatically create a unique id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation).  However, if for some reason you want to generate the id in python, you could use [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Comment: nope, it raise error TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the [ES Python Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch) you will not be able to use `es.create(...)` without an ID.  You should instead `es.index(...)` instead.

Both of them call the Elasticsearch [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html), but `es.create` sets the `op_type` parameter to `create`, and `es.index` to `index`.

The `create` operation is designed to fail if the ID already exists, so it will not accept being called without an ID.

Comment: small note. using `es.index()` but setting `op_type='create'` will still give errors. The defeault setting of `op_type='index'` should be use